# Change auto-comment from "not an answer" review queue

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, low-quality-posts

Apparently (at least I've been [told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27570758/r-how-to-use-bounds-and-the-port-algorithm-in-nlslist#comment43567825_27570835) that when complaining), the review queue auto-posts the following comment, when someone without deleting privilege votes that an answer should be deleted because it is a question.

> If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask
>   Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a
>   link to this question if it helps provide context.

This will often be bad advice because usually if a question is posted as an answer there are also problems with question quality, which ensures down-votes and closing of the question. Thus, I propose to change the second sentence to something like this:

> Please make also sure that your question fits Stack Overflow's quality
>   standards. You should [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)
>   for an introduction.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. People who don't understand that answers aren't for asking questions aren't *usually* the people who ask thought through well articulated questions. Pointing them in a the direction of a page that explains how SO works is a good idea.

Comment: The Ask Question page that the link leads to has some guidelines directly on the page, and a link to the help center. I guess it wouldn't hurt to emphasize it more, but people are directed towards help if they follow the link.

Comment: I think the advice to link the original question should not vanish.

Answer (score 20):

**This is a great idea** *and no brainer for me.*

I have been wondering about proposing it myself. Coincidetally, I just came across a very poor question submitted as an answer and I saw that someone was leaving the auto-comment.

I felt the urge to point out that for the OP so that even if it is resubmitted as a new question will probably be closed (or even deleted?) in no time. Therefore, I left a comment to clarify this, but if I do not do that, the OP may have led him/herself into double frustration.

So, yes, please change it as it is a very easy, yet useful change. I do not mean to redocument the help center in comments for sure, but a short hint inline would suffice. I guess many of them do not bother to follow the link or even understand the importance of it.